# How to align center elements in this CodePen?

Tags: html, css

http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/ACJta

**^ Updated (I can never get SASS to work right in Codepen)**

Can't align to the middle my elements above. Using SASS, I want to avoid using `position` hacks

```
<main>
  <div class="gradient">
    <div class="hero">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt=""/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <section class="tagline">
    <h1>Hi there Lorem Ipsum <em>My name is Bob</em></h1>
    <button>Learn More</button>
  </section>
</main>
```

```
body {
  font-family:Arial
}

.hero {
    display: table-cell;
    //position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    // top: 42%;
    // left: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    height: 447px;
    vertical-align: bottom;

    img {
        width: 300px;
        height: 280px;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: bottom;
        border:0;
    }
}

.tagline {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    color: blue;
    background: gray;
    z-index: 2;

    h1 {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-top: 5%;
        width: 80%;
        font-size: 42px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    em {
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    button {
        margin-top: 25px;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: em(21);
        color: white;
        border: 0;
        background: orange;
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated codepen, had to remove SASS, still can't get the image in the top to center align: http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/ACJta

Comment: Which elements, to the middle of what..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to center your elements above my doing the following:

```
.hero {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 447px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

It seems it did not want to center because you had specified `width: auto`